# Apache Camel on Quarkus - CXF SOAP - Problem with localhost:8080

Tags: maven, soap, apache-camel, cxf, quarkus

I am using Quarkus Apache Camel. I want to use camel-quarkus-cxf-soap. I tried this:
https://code.quarkus.io/?e=org.apache.camel.quarkus%3Acamel-quarkus-cxf-soap&extension-search=camel-quarkus-cxf-soap

If I to start the application (mvn quarkus:dev) and browse to http://localhost:8080 then the below text is shown:
"No services have been found."
And the title of the page is:
"CXF - Service list"

Also, when I start the application I get the info log below. (I guess this *might* be a part of my problem.)
"Mapping a Vert.x handler for CXF to /* as requested by [camel-cxf-soap]"

When I browse to http://localhost:8080/q/health I get the same text:
"No services have been found."
And I also get a warning log:
"Can't find the request for http://localhost:8080/q/health's Observer"

I would like my application to work like this:

1. Browsing to http://localhost:8080 shows the web page that *I* defined myself.
2. Browsing to http://localhost:8080/q/health and get a result showing the health of the Quarkus Camel application.
3. Still be able to call a SOAP service from my application.

Regards
Magnus

Comment: There is a known issue with hosting the CXF endpoints on `/*`. It's probably best avoided for now. See https://github.com/apache/camel-quarkus/issues/4192.

Answer (score 0):

I worked around this issue by setting the property "quarkus.cxf.path" in "application.properties" to "/cxf".